# Why is there a left inverse for an injective Function with the empty set as domain?

Tags: functions, inverse

The fact that a function is injective is equivalent to the fact that there is a left inverse. Now consider $f:\mathbb{∅}\to \mathbb{A}$ where $\mathbb{A}$ is non-empty. Wouldn't the left inverse be defined to map from a non-empty to an empty set? If so, this wouldn't be a function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right. This is not a function. So any map from the empty set to a non-empty set does not have a left inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite correct. Among functions [*with non-empty domains*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective#Injections_can_be_undone), injectivity is equivalent to the existence of a left-inverse, and the restriction is crucial for precisely this reason.

So, we can say the following:

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is injective if and only if $X=\emptyset$ or there exists a function $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_Y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I came across it in Amann and Escher's "Calculus 1". I guess I will communicate the missing precondiction. A great place here, by the way.

Comment: You're very welcome. Given that it's a calculus text, I suspect that it is an implicit assumption that functions have non-empty domains. (P.S.: I rather like it here, myself.)

Comment: Actually, empty domains are explicitly mentioned including that you cannnot have an empty codomain for a function. I can really recommend this book.